# Playback of large compressed bag with /clock

Tags: ros, rosbag, compressed

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having a strange issue.

When I try to play a compressed bag file it looks like the clock deadlocks and stops publishing to /clock.  All other topics though seem to be published fine.

Playing back the original uncompressed bag works fine.

eg. `rosbag play --clock compressed.bag`  - clock stops,
`rosbag play --clock original.bag`  - plays fine

Is anyone else seeing anything similar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78676/playback-of-large-compressed-bag-with-/clock/) by [Matt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1965/matt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-06-02**:
Could you provide a downloadable bag file where this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be a bug (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/82) in rostopic.

(Too low karma to post a link. Will edit when possible)

---

Originally posted by [lucasb.eyer.be](https://answers.ros.org/users/14676/lucasb.eyer.be/) with karma: 61 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1